# Conditionally filtering parquets based on parameters provided to function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, amazon-emr

I have a set of partitioned parquets I'm attempting to read in Spark. To simplify filtering, I've written a wrapper function to optionally allow filtering based on the parquets' partition columns. The parquets are partitioned by date then hour. I'm having some trouble understanding what conditions are necessary to cause Spark to pushdown the filtering and not attempt to list all leafs of the S3 bucket containing the parquet. Is it necessary for me to run the filtering at the time the `events` variable is instantiated?

```
  def readFromParquet(session: SparkSession, start: Option[Timestamp] = Option.empty, end: Option[Timestamp] = Option.empty): Dataset[Event] = {
    import session.implicits._

    var events = session
      .read
      .parquet("s3a://precomputes/events")

    if (start.isDefined) {
      val startDate = Date.valueOf(start.get.toLocalDateTime.toLocalDate)
      val hour = start.get.toInstant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getHour
      events = events.where(
        'date > startDate ||
          ('date === startDate && 'hour >= hour)
      )
    }
    if (end.isDefined) {
      val endDate = Date.valueOf(end.get.toLocalDateTime.toLocalDate)
      val hour = end.get.toInstant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getHour
      events = events.where(
        'date < endDate ||
          ('date === endDate && 'hour <= hour)
      )
    }

    events
      .as[Event]
      .alias("events")
  }
```

Thanks!

**Update 2023-04-05**

Re: Andrew Long's comment, the physical plan is

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) ColumnarToRow
+- FileScan parquet [...] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[s3a://precomputes/events], PartitionFilters: [((date#31 > 2023-04-05) OR ((date#31 = 2023-04-05) AND (hour#32 >= 12))), ((date#31 < 2023-04-05..., PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<...
```

so it does look like the partitions are being filtered, but Spark still lists all leaf nodes. Shouldn't that be prevented when using partition filters?

Comment: when you do df.explain(...) what are you currently getting?  What does the final physical plan look like?

Answer (score 0):

when you do df.explain(...) what are you currently getting? What does the final physical plan look like?

```
var events = session
      .read
      .parquet("s3a://precomputes/events")
```

This may prevent you from doing partition filtering as spark may not think this is partitioned and is just a folder of files.  What you likely want todo is run a CREATE TABLE command to and then run MSCK repair table to load the partition definitions into the catalog.

```
spark.sql("""CREATE TABLE t1 (name STRING, age INT) USING parquet PARTITIONED BY (age)
     location "/tmp/namesAndAges.parquet"""")
spark.sql(""" MSCK REPAIR TABLE t1""")
```

You will then be able todo

```
spark.read.table("db.my_table").where("my_partition_col > 2001-1-1")....
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-repair-table.html

https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/partition-filters-pushed-filters/